# (Ruby) Cannot use selenium commands in cucumber tests?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I am trying to save object definitions in a "home page" file and simply call those methods whenever I need to use that button/link/image/etc.  But for some reason the selenium commands are bringing up a `NoMethodError`.  When I simply run the `cucumber` command while on the features folder in the terminal, I get these errors:

```
When I click on Site Management           # features/step_definitions/steps.rb:17
  undefined method `find_element' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  ./features/lib/pages/home.rb:3:in `siteMgmt'
  ./features/step_definitions/steps.rb:18:in `/^I click on Site Management$/'
  features/test.feature:6:in `When I click on Site Management'
```

So in other words, it's trying to "click on site management," the code moves to the Home class, the SiteMgmt method (great!) and then fails when trying to run the selenium `find_method` method.  I thought I might have to add a `require selenium-webdriver` at the top of `home.rb`, but a) that's NOT the case in `steps.rb` and, even if I add it, it doesn't work.

Here is the folder structure:

```
features/
    --test.feature
    lib/
        pages/
            --home.rb
    step_definitions/
        --steps.rb
    support/
        --env.rb
```

env.rb

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../lib/pages/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }

Before do |scenario|
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  @url = "URL goes here"
end

After do |scenario|
  @driver.quit
end
```

test.feature

```
Feature: Proof of Concept
  Stack overflow help!

  Scenario:
    Given I am logged into the site
    When I click on Site Management
    Then the Site Management page should load
```

steps.rb

```
Given(/^I am logged into AMP$/) do
  @driver.get @amp_url
end

When(/^I click on Site Management$/) do
  link = Home.new.siteMgmt
  link.click
end

Then(/^the Site Management page should load$/) do
  # assert here
end
```

home.rb

```
class Home
    def siteMgmt
        elem = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="body"]/section[2]/ul/li[1]/h3/a')
        return elem
    end
end
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@driver` instance variable that's created in the `Before` block isn't available to an instantiated `Home` object. You could add a parameter to the `site_mgmt` method and pass the `@driver` instance variable in.  Here's a contrived example:

```
class Home
  def site_mgmt(driver)
    elem = driver.find_element(:id, "logo")
  end
end

require 'selenium-webdriver'

@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
@driver.navigate.to "http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved"

link = Home.new.site_mgmt(@driver)
link.click
```

A couple of notes: 1) variables in ruby are snake_case'd (i.e. `site_mgmt` instead of `siteMgmt`; and 2) `return elem` in `site_mgmt` isn't needed because ruby methods implicitly return.

Comment: Thanks!  I added a simpler fix, at least for me, but I GREATLY appreciate your answer!  Have an upvote!

Answer (score -1):

Well, it turns out all I had to do is turn @driver to $driver. I'm still learning Ruby and didn't realize the difference.